# How can I make my React context provider type safe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-context

I have a React context provider. I wrote it in JS but I'm now rewriting it in TS. I'm having a hell of a time getting the types to work properly. The context is initialized with undefined. Later it is set with an `action` property, which can be any `ActionCreator` and an `args` property which can be any `Action`. I've tried a couple of different approaches but it's like whack a mole. This is what I currently have:

```
import { createContext, FC, PropsWithChildren, useState } from 'react'
import { Action, ActionCreator } from 'redux'
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

type ModalStateT = {
  action: ActionCreator<any> | undefined
  args: Action | undefined
}

type ModalContextT = {
  modalState: ModalStateT
  setModalState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ModalStateT>>
  resetModalState: ({action, args}: ModalStateT) => void
}

export const ModalContext = createContext<ModalContextT | undefined>(undefined)

const ModalProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {

  const defaultState = {
    action: undefined,
    args: undefined,
  }
  const [modalState, setModalState] = useState(defaultState)

  const resetModalState = () => {
    setModalState(defaultState)
  }
  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider value={{ modalState, setModalState, resetModalState }}>
      { children }
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default ModalProvider
```

My IDE does shows errors here `value={{ modalState, setModalState, resetModalState }}`

This is the error I get:

```
TS2322: Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ action: undefined; args: undefined; }>>' is not assignable to type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<ModalStateT>>'.
Type 'SetStateAction<ModalStateT>' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<{ action: undefined; args: undefined; }>'.
Type 'ModalStateT' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<{ action: undefined; args: undefined; }>'.
Type 'ModalStateT' is not assignable to type '{ action: undefined; args: undefined; }'. Types of property 'action' are incompatible.           
Type 'ActionCreator<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.        
Type 'ActionCreator<any>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you mean "but I'm now rewriting it in TS"?

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/context/

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I fixed it. Thank you.

Comment: @Camilo that looks like a very helpful resource. Thank you for sharing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotate your `defaultState` with the `ModalStateT` type:

```
const defaultState: ModalStateT = {
  action: undefined,
  args: undefined,
}
```

otherwise TypeScript will infer a more restrictive type.

That is why it's giving you errors like:

```
Type 'ActionCreator<any>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
```

That is TypeScript telling you that it's inferred the type as `undefined` instead of the less restrictive `ActionCreator<any> | undefined` that you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed. I'm still getting used to what TS can infer and what it can't.

Comment: To add to this answer: Personally, I would kill the `| undefined` on the context type by giving it an initial dummy value.  Move the `defaultState` variable outside of the component.  Define `export const ModalContext = createContext<ModalContextT>({ modalState: defaultState, setModalState: () => undefined, resetModalState: () => undefined });`  It also seems like the type for `resetModalState` is incorrect as it does not require any arguments.  It should be `() => void` instead of `({action, args}: ModalStateT) => void`.